# Is "aptitude full-upgrade" safe to run on a new server?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

Is it safe to run this command on a brand new Debian server?

```
aptitude -y full-upgrade
```

The command is from http://www.linode.com/stackscripts/view/?StackScriptID=1

On a related note, how is **aptitude update** different from **apt-get update**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it's safe; what's the risk? If the server's brand new, you have no data to lose, and no services to get complaints about.

From the aptitude manpage:

> **full-upgrade**
>
> Upgrades installed packages to their most recent version, removing
>   or installing packages as necessary. This command is less
>   conservative than `safe-upgrade` and thus more likely to perform
>   unwanted actions. However, it is capable of upgrading packages
>   that `safe-upgrade` cannot upgrade.
>
> *Note*
>   This command was originally named `dist-upgrade` for historical
>   reasons, and aptitude still recognizes `dist-upgrade` as a
>   synonym for full-upgrade.

Generally speaking, it's fine. The difference between apt and aptitude the algorithm for dependency solvers. Eventually you can expect apt-get to be replaced underneath by aptitude, when it's improved to the point where it's better than apt-get in every case.

Comment: Generally speaking, should I be using aptitude instead of apt-get?

Comment: Generally, it doesn't matter at all. Sometimes, when things go horribly wrong, aptitude can calculate a way out with fewer remove packages, but typically the distinction is irrelevant

Comment: From the DebianWiki on Aptitude: "Score-based and (usually) smarter dependency resolver than apt-get. 
aptitude is also non-fattening, naturally cleansing, and housebroken..." http://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude . The Debian FAQ is a little bit more serious and states: "Note that aptitude is the preferred program for package management from console both for package installations and package or system upgrades." http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-pkgtools.en.html

Comment: FWIW the thinking has changed at Debian and they now suggest using 'apt' instead of 'apt-get' or 'aptitude'